# Assembly sum with different size numbers

Tags: assembly, x86

Can I sum different bits (8 bit with 16 bit) number in assembly?

For example;

```
 sums proc near
 mov ax,0280h
 mov bh,30h
 mov ch,20h
 adc ax,bh
 adc ax,ch
 ret 
 sums endp
```

This code gives an error; "operant types dont match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

```
mov ax,33h
mov cx,1133h
add ax,cx
```

Comment: That's adding two 16-bit numbers.

Comment: al = 8bits ax = 16 bits (0 padding is only for the addition)

Comment: I have just updated the question. Could you please look at the example? Thanks.

Comment: careful, you cannot directly add ch and ax. You have to add cx to ax and it will work.

Comment: Why I can't add ch and cx directly? ch is 8 bits and can't it complete itself to 16 bit with zeros?

Comment: well, on the registers low level everything has to be precise. It's not like a high level language. For a processor, it's important that things are done the way the have to. No place for high level magic here :)

Comment: @Baran, your own question points out that it can't. A processor could obviously be given the ability to perform such operations, but that would require more opcodes, and there are only so many bits to play with

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Just load the 8-bit value into a register and sign-extend or zero-extend it.  Then add.

Comment: +1 for a somewhat underspecified answer to a somewhat underspecified question. :-)

Comment: Thanks I have just edited my question with a sample code. Can you please review it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, so correct me if I'm wrong (NASM - AT & T syntax)

```
 .section .text

 .globl _start
_start:
 movl $0, %eax
 mov $0x280, %ax
 movl $0, %ebx
 movl $0, %ecx
 mov $0x30, %bh
 mov $0x20, %ch
 add %bx, %ax
 add %cx, %ax

 movl %eax, %ebx    # store the result in %ebx
 movl $1, %eax      # syscall for exit()
 int $0x80
```

If you are on Linux, after running this application on the console, execute:

```
echo $?
```

to print the return code of the app, which is actually the sum we did before (and stored in `%ebx`).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mov bh,30h
mov ch,20h
adc ax,bh
adc ax,ch
```

to

```
mov bx,30h
mov cx,20h
adc ax,bx
adc ax,cx
```